# What is a" feature envy" code and why is it considered a code smell?

Tags: refactoring, code-reviews, clean-code, code-smell

This [question on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2909321/how-do-i-correct-feature-envy-in-this-case) talks about  correcting what the OP thought is *feature envy* code. Another example where I saw this nifty phrase being quoted is in a [recently given answer here](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/212100/60189) in programmers.SE. Although I did drop in a [comment](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/212094/correct-comment-to-put-for-boolean-function-arguments-that-are-false/212100#comment418401_212100) to that answer asking for the information I thought it would of general help to programmers following Q&A to understand what is meant by the term *feature-envy*. Please feel free to edit additional tags if you think appropriate.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How large is ok for a Class?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/11846/how-large-is-ok-for-a-class) See also: [Is it a code smell if an object knows a lot of its owner?](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/100537/is-it-a-code-smell-if-an-object-knows-a-lot-of-its-owner)

Answer (score 119, accepted):

[Feature envy](https://blog.codinghorror.com/code-smells/) is a term used to describe a situation in which one object gets at the fields of another object in order to perform some sort of computation or make a decision, rather than asking the object to do the computation itself.

As a trivial example, consider a class representing a rectangle. The user of the rectangle may need to know its area. The programmer could expose `width` and `height` fields and then do the computation outside of the `Rectangle` class. Alternatively, `Rectangle` could keep the `width` and `height` fields private and provide a `getArea` method. This is arguably a better approach.

The problem with the first situation, and the reason it is considered a code smell, is because it breaks encapsulation.

As a rule of thumb, whenever you find yourself making extensive use of fields from another class to perform any sort of logic or computation, consider moving that logic to a method on the class itself.

Comment: +1, though your example is not realistic, since a useful Rectangle class would typically expose width and height fields either.

Comment: And though the breaking of encapsulation *may* a occur together with "Feature envirism", in most real-world examples I have seen so far it was probably not the case. It happens more in situations "hey, I need to compute some things just in the code using that object, and I am not sure if I can touch that object's implementation / if we should give the object the responsibility for that computation". And then one implements the calculation using fields **which are already exposed** (though a much cleaner implementation would be probably possible within the object).

Comment: @DocBrown Imagine a rectangle drawn on the surface of a torus, cone or sphere.  If my shape-drawing library produces objects which are capable of producing the correct results in such contexts, you'd be foolish not  to leave them to calculate their own areas - in any context.

Comment: Let's say you had some DTO's that represented a rectangle, .. they get serialized to json and get used on the client. Calculating the area in that case will happen on the client side? Or would you advise to have an "area" property that gets calculated on the server side? (with a CalculateArea() function inside the DTO? or outside? In a lot of modern situations the whole thing isn't quite as clear. Where to put what, depends a LOT on the situation I guess :)

Comment: @DocBrown I'm curious, does the concept of feature envy as a code smell contradict the arguments given here? http://www.drdobbs.com/cpp/how-non-member-functions-improve-encapsu/184401197
Some excerpts: "Adding functions beyond the minimum necessary to let clients get their jobs done decreases the class's comprehensibility and maintainability." "The addition of member functions beyond those truly required violates the open/closed principle, yields fat class interfaces, and ultimately leads to software rot."

Comment: @OskarN.: By definition we're talking about functions that *are* needed. They're obviously needed if other classes are re-implementing them over and over again.

Comment: @OskarN.: it depends; sometimes the decision is clear, sometimes its a matter of taste, and most often its a matter of experience. In your article, there are good reasons why Scott Meyers writes "**sometimes** less is more", and that it took him years to understand when *not* to apply his "algorithm for deciding when to make f a member function".

Comment: @Aaronaught: re-implementing can be also avoided by placing a reusable function in a common place *outside* the class in stake, so that's neither a pro- or counter argument.

Comment: @DocBrown: Not really, that's just a slightly more subtle case of feature envy that's almost equally likely to lead to spaghetti code. Unless you *can't* modify the class, you should follow the [Tell, Don't Ask](http://martinfowler.com/bliki/TellDontAsk.html) rule.

Comment: @itsbruce: If an object like a rectangle includes an "area" property, its contract should specify what that property means and what invariants clients are entitled to rely upon. Even setting aside topological issues, if e.g. the area, height, and width are reported using type `float` but might be internally stored as `double`, there may be value in specifying that the reported area will always be the *reported* height times the reported width, or specifying that the area may be computed using higher-precision values.  What's important is that people implementing the class and those using it...

Comment: ...have compatible expectations.  Guaranteeing that the indicated equality holds might be helpful for consumers, but would constrain implementation; expressly stating that such equality may not hold may interfere with some things consumers could otherwise do with the class, but would reserve some freedom for future implementations.  Unfortunately, many class designers neither grant freedom to consumers nor reserve it to implementers, yielding a worst-of-both-worlds scenario.

Comment: Width and height don’t need to be private. Plenty of situations where I need them. Calculating the area is something the rectangle would know best how to do.

Answer (score 2):

There is a possible situation when it is OK to use another class/struct methods extensively - when your class/struct is a container for data. Usually there is a little you can do with this data without external context.

Such classes can still hold some internal logic but more often they are used as containers:

```
class YourUid {
 public:
  YourUid(int id_in_workplace_, int id_in_living_place_, DB* FBI_database, int id_in_FBI_database);
  bool IsInvalidWorker() const { return id_in_workplace == consts::invalid_id_in_workplace; }
  bool CanMessWith() const { return !FBI_database_.is_cool(id_in_FBI_database_); }
  int id_in_workplace;
  int id_in_living_place;
 private:
  int id_in_FBI_database_;
  const DB* FBI_database_;
};
```

@jhewlett in his answer refers to this article to prove that you should no use other class members extensively, but there is another *code smells* situation described there with advocates my example:

> Long Parameter List. Limit the number of parameters you need in a given
>   method, or use an object to combine the parameters.

Comment: how does this answer the question asked?

Comment: @gnat The Q is about Why it is considered "code smell". jhewlett gives an A with some too general assumtions questioned in the comments. My answer is 2 cents to distinguish "code smell" from normal practice.