Is it still "feature envy" if the state to make decision or the action to take after asking the state involves other classes to participate?
According to https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/212130/432039, if a class asks another class for the state, and then call methods of that class, it is called "feature envy", eg:
if(a.state){
  a.doSomething();
}

it should move the code into the object as an instance method:
public class A{
    public void someMethod(){
        if(this.state){
            this.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
.
.
.
a.someMethod();

However, the answer only talks about the case that both the state and the action to take have only one "other class" to participate, what if there are other things that participate the state? eg:
if(a.state && b.state){
  a.doSomething();
}

is it also a kind of feature envy and hence should modify as follows:
public class A{
    public void someMethod(boolean bState){
        if(this.state && bState){
            this.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
.
.
.
a.someMethod(b.state);

? Or if other things also participate the action, eg:
if(a.state){
  a.doSomething();
  c.doSomething();
}

Should it modify as follows?
public class A{
    public void someMethod(C c){
        if(this.state){
            this.doSomething();
            c.doSomething();
        }
    }
}
.
.
.
a.someMethod(c);

And what if there are "else" actions to do, eg:
if(a.state){
  a.doSomething();
}else{
  d.doSomething();
}

? Should I refactor it? If so, how to refactor it?

Honestly, it sounds like perhaps the state and the action should be separated. Won't that solve all those issues?

Do you have a clear case? Like a real example, not just A + B but something real. It may be for example that you need a class C which groups the A + B states because it is really another object. Like: A = Wheel, B = Engine then C might be Car which is the object you want to interact with: Car->StartEngine->ReleaseWheels


if a class asks another class for the state, and then call methods of that class, it should move the code into the object as an instance method

No, that is not what the cited answer says. It says

As a rule of thumb, [] consider moving that logic ...

For me, this means

"When you encounter the described case, switch on your brain, start thinking hard whether it makes sense to move the code in stake into the object as an instance method (or not) in the specific context, and then use your best judgement".

Context is king. Sensible decisions on "which code belongs into which method or class" are not made by just looking at the structure, at meaningless names like class A, doSomething or someMethod. Sensible decisions are made by thinking about

the semantics, like what kind of abstraction class A or someMethod create.

the layers or libraries of your system, which code fits best into which layer or which library

the possibility of reusing certain code, which may be easier when the code is part of a certain class, layer or library

the dependencies - moving certain code into certain places can create cyclic dependencies or resolve them, or eliminate certain dependencies at all


And yes, the question which objects and classes will be involved, especially when there is more than one object or class to consider, is also part of that decision - but not exclusively, and definitely not by just counting their numbers.

The answer by @Doc Brown gives really highlights the fact that you need to be thinking and planning your code well.
I just wanted to add a concrete example of what I would do with your code. In this code (from the question, the current object depends on state from multiple components. (Assuming reasonable abstraction, I read this as "The state of my current object is an aggregation of the states of its components).
if(a.state && b.state){
  a.doSomething();
}

We could clarify the scope of the state as follows:
private bool condition(){
  return (a.state && b.state);
}

if(this.condition()){
  a.doSomething();
}

Then, since our scope of the state is our current object, maybe the resulting action should also be at the same scope:
private void doAction(){
  a.doSomething()
}

if(this.condition()){
  this.doAction()
}

Now, the code is clear that the parent object (main context) is acting based on "its own" state, where the state is an aggregation of details from a lower level scope, and the action to take is coordinated by the parent object, even if its just a delegation to a single object at a lower scope.
Further benefit:

condition (parent) and a.state/b.state (details) has the opportunity to introduce a new name. Only you know your context, but naming this particular aggregation of detailed state will help with the abstraction of the parent object
same applies to doAction (parent) and a.doSomething (details)

Of course, the details may differ depending on what exactly a and b are. (constructor parameters stored on the instance, function parameters, etc.).
Exercise to the reader: How would you handle an else action?
